# Resource Busy Error in Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run the demo here for using WCF in Xamarin [here](http://nullskull.com/a/10476786/xamarin-cross-platform-application-consuming-wcf--part-2.aspx)

The Android app compiles but I get the error below when trying to run the iphone app

I have restarted my MAC and reattached the phone and keep getting this

I was trying to use this in Visual Studio (using Parallels) initially, then I changed over to try it Xamarin studio

codesign -v -f -s "572B56F74A74705027876BB948164ED500CC3E37" "--resource-rules=/Volumes/C/temp/XamarinWCF/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/iOS.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Volumes/C/temp/XamarinWCF/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/iOS.xcent" "/Volumes/C/temp/XamarinWCF/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/iOS.app"
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
/Volumes/C/temp/XamarinWCF/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/iOS.app: Resource busy

Does anyone have any idea?

Paul

Comment: If you open your XamarinWCF.csproj on Mac with text editor(or right-click in Solution view(View->Pads->Solution) and do "Tools->Edit file"). What is value inside "CodesignResourceRules" element? Wondering if it's full Windows path... It should be relative path to ResourceRules.plist inside your project. Also try Rebuild all.

Answer (score 0):

I am marking this as closed because it appears to have fixed itself by another complete restart of all devices

I still cannot get WCF to work in anyway for Xamarin but I think I will probably need to cover that elsewhere